# Display specific template on $routeChangeError

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a feeling there is no way to do this, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask. I'm using `route.resolve` to check the current user status when routes change and determine if they are authorized for that route. Assuming they aren't, ideally I'd like to simple display an error template rather than change routes to point to an error page.

Obviously the latter is more straightforward but it doesn't feel right. Is it possible to handle it this way or will have to get more creative here.

One solution I've considered is to have  directives in the root template that show based on an $rooteScope.errorState is set. Not my favourite solution but a workable one for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-route` doesn't natively support that, you could make it work but it requires some effort. However, you can use http://angular-route-segment.com/.

It enhances `ng-route` with `resolveFailed` option so you can define a new set of controller and template to use when resolver fails.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if ui-router might support this situation too. Just checking this out and it seems like it's pretty good. Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisNicola might be, I didn't try `ui-route` before. http://angular-route-segment.com/ uses `ng-route` internally, and `ui-route` use its own mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up with which uses just the core ngRoute module. A custom directive might make this a bit cleaner but this does work.

```
  $rootScope.$on '$routeChangeStart', (e, route) ->
    $rootScope.errorTemplateUrl = null

  $rootScope.$on '$routeChangeError', (e, c, p, error) ->
    $rootScope.errorTemplateUrl = views['errors/' + error]
```

In my project `views[]` is a list of shortcut names to templates. In this case I can pass something like `views['errors/404']` however you can get the error template url any way you like. Then in my base view I have.

```
<div ng-if="!errorTemplateUrl" ng-view></div>
<div ng-if="errorTemplateUrl" ng-include="errorTemplateUrl"></div>
```

If resolves fail I can reject and pass the name of the error template that I would like to display to this which then displays it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

edit: misunderstood question

in your resolver, when access denied is detected, call this

```
$templateCache.put('template.html', 'Access Denied');
```

and then resolve the route as successful. Where template.html is the location of your templateUrl.

Comment: Right but the objective here was to not change the route path, but just display the error.