# angularjs routes, how to check if template file exists

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using angularjs in my application, all works well but before loading the template I just want to check that it actually exists on its given path.

Here is my code :

```
    .when("/:page", angularAMD.route({

        templateUrl: function (rp) { 
                     return 'public/templates/' + rp.page.replace('.html', '') + '.php'; },

        resolve: {
        load: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$location', 
            function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {

                 var path = $location.path();
                 //console.log(path);
                 var parsePath = path.split("/");

                 var controllerName = parsePath[1];
                 controllerName = controllerName.replace('.html', '').replace('_', '');
                 var loadController = "public/js/controllers/" +  
                                       controllerName + "Controller.js";

                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 require([loadController], function () {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                 });
            });
            return deferred.promise;
            }]
        }

    }))
```

I want that before doing this `return 'public/templates/' + rp.page.replace('.html', '') + '.php'; }` it must check if this file exists, otherwise I want to redirect to 404 page.

what now happens is, when I visits some invalid link, I dont get 404 status, instead it loads the main index.html file, and for that reason, it starts running the same code in an infinite loop, at last browser hangs.

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Then why don't you use $routeChangeError or notFound(something) event for better implementation of what you thought to redirect user to else page?

Comment: can you please provide me some example, how to use $routeChangeError ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894568/display-specific-template-on-routechangeerror checkout this.

Comment: my problem is that I dont get error on route change first of all, but instead of loading the template file, it loads the main index.html file, and I am unable to detect any not-found errors, I have a solution in my mind btw, what about sending ajax request to that file and then use that status codes ? what you think about it ? good or bad.

Comment: lets say you visit invalid link in your angularjs app. at that moment you don't need to do anything. if its invalid (not registered in your routings), app will automatically raise $routeChangeError event (only fires when no registered route is found). at this point , for invalid link you don't need to check whether your template is available or not. just because of that $routeChangeError event you can redirect user to your custom 404 page. I hope I've given you clear idea !

Comment: but routes are not defined anywhere ? its like `/:page`, so if somebody types in URL mydomain.com/tos but tos.html page dont exists, then I want to return 404 page.

Comment: http://www.cnblogs.com/Answer1215/p/3936316.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501962/how-to-handle-resource-not-found-with-angularjs-routing

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? Nothing on here yet actually solves the issue.

Comment: @MurraySmith No this thing is still a mystery for me. No solution.

Answer (score 1):

In ngRoute, you need to configure the routes in the `config` block, and inside config block you can't use factories and services, 
 so you can use a simple trick to check if template exists, and if not return your 404 page.

```
var checkTplUrl = function(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return (http.status !== 404) ? url : './404.html';
};
```

```
.when("/:page", angularAMD.route({

    templateUrl: function (rp) {
        return checkTplUrl('public/templates/' + rp.page.replace('.html', '') + '.php'); },

    resolve: {
        load: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$location',
            function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {

                var path = $location.path();
                //console.log(path);
                var parsePath = path.split("/");

                var controllerName = parsePath[1];
                controllerName = controllerName.replace('.html', '').replace('_', '');
                var loadController = "public/js/controllers/" +
                        controllerName + "Controller.js";

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                require([loadController], function () {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }]
    }

}))
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/1UjlFgT7dazMZOrAhZzY?p=info

Comment: When I run this function in a general route with a parameter it always returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (or $scope.$on)
 $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, eventObj) {
    //redirect your user to custom 404 page;
  });
```

Comment: but where do I place this code ? in the `load: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$location',` section ? I tried here already, not working, the reason is that I never get error even if the URL is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should just do in any non-trivial angular.js app, probably the best place for them is right where you define your mainmodule, then a config block and then a run block.

Without handling and logging those $routeChange Events (resp. when using ui-router $stateChange Events) you are basically blind and will miss errors and duplicate route changes and other nasty things...

Here the example when using ui-router, if using angular basic routing use the respecitve events of angular router.

```
angular.module('yourMainModuleName', ['your dependencies'])

.config(['$someProvider', function(someProvider) {
    // do setup all your global providers here
    // e.g. $http, restangular, ui-router, angular-translate....

}   ])

.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 
function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams ) {

    // put ui-router $state on $rootScope, so we have access to it in all $scopes
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            // always see what happens in your app!
            console.debug('stateChangeStart from: ' + (fromState && fromState.name) + ' to: ' + toState.name);
            // handle auth here as well, check whether user is allowed to go to this state, abort if not
            ...
        });

         $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            // see what happens in your app!
            console.debug('stateChangeSuccess from: ' + (fromState && fromState.name) + ' to: ' + toState.name);
         });

        // log stateChangeErrors
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            console.log('Error on StateChange from: "' + (fromState && fromState.name) + '" to:  "'+ toState.name + '", err:' + error.message + ", code: " + error.status);
            $state.go('home');
         });

}]);
```

Comment: I understand this thing, but my problem is that my script dont return error, here is an example, suppose I run this URL `mydomain.com/hello.html`, now script will return the template file from this path `public/templates/hello.html` but this hello.html actually dont exists at all, so instead of loading this file or giving error, it loads the index.html, which is the main application file, where we include the angularjs libs and bcoz of including index.html, it loads the angularjs libs in loop, hence tons of ajax calls and at last browser crash, I hope I am able to explain my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that check if the file exist and returns a promise!

```
$http.head("template2check").then(function () {
                return true;
            }, function () {
                return false;
            });
```

In the controller use the service:

```
<service>.<service method>.then(function (found) {
     if (found) {......
});
```