# Ionic not changing views/state unless it is a tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a tab bar system in my Ionic app. However I wanted to have some views that weren't apart of the tab bar and were just a sepertate page to be opened by a button.. For some reason whenever the page isn't a tab it will not open the view. I can see the URL change but it will not change to that view unless the view is also a tab as well. Hopefully that makes sense. I initially was trying to switch pages using Href, but then decided to try ng-click when href wasn't working.. here is my code below..

Where I have the state defined:

```
       .state('tab.friendsadd', {
        url: "/friendsadd",
         templateUrl: "templates/friends-add.html"

})
```

Here is the button I had that would call the function:

```
            <button class="button button-clear button-assertive" ng-       click="changeview()">New Group</button>
```

and then here is my changeview() function, which I know is called correctly because the statement is printed:

```
  $scope.changeview = function() {
  console.log("hey why isnt this working");
  $state.go("tab.friendsadd"); //change state

}
```

Not sure if this could be the issue but here is my template for the new view that I am trying to open as well:

```
<script id="templates/friends-add.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Sign-In">
        <ion-content>
          <p> Header </p>
    <p> Tom brady </p>

        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help. I hope this is an easy fix...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.state('friendsadd', {
        url: "/friendsadd",
        templateUrl: "templates/friends-add.html"
})
```

and this in the html

```
<button class="button button-clear button-assertive" href="#/friendsadd" ui-sref="friendsadd">New Group</button>
```

and if your template is an actual file, then you don't need the `<script></script>` tags

If this won't solve it or even if it will, add some debugging to your routes 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28750792/4050230

Hope this helps..